# Where do I find these avatars?

Tags: stock-images

There was a pack with avatars like this on a website and they were offered for free, but I can't remember the name or URL...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those avatars look like they were created with the Flash avatar maker ["Create my Picture"](http://planetcreation.co.uk/createpic/). The app can also be found [at this link](http://scorpionse.ucoz.ru/swf_raznoe/rf_av.swf).

Neither of these links is likely to be the original site for the application.

Answer (score 3):

[Google reverse image lookup](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searchbyimage.html) says www.iconator.com for the second one, but I'm not sure how long I want to spend trawling around their site...

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't appear that's the source :(